# Where to upload and how to start a node js app?

Tags: node.js

I have installed node js on my cent os server, it is working fine.
I have developed a node js app on my local machine, it works fine.

However, I cannot seem to find any documentation about:

1. Where to upload my app to in the node js install.
2. How to start my app once it is uploaded.

I found some tutorials that refer to something called 'express'. But this seems to be for building your app on the linux server.

Where do I upload my app in the node js install and, once uploaded, how do I start it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to upload your Node.js application anywhere - just open a cmd shell and run the command `node yourapp.js`:

`node` - opens the node.exe which is located at `C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.js` by default.
`yourapp.js` - the path of the javascript file that contains the code to run.

[**Express**](http://expressjs.com/) is a very useful node.js framework. It has nothing to do with linux specifically - it works on every operation system:

> Express is a minimal and flexible node.js web application framework,
>   providing a robust set of features for building single and multi-page,
>   and hybrid web applications.

Here is a sample of how to create a simple express application:

```
// This is how you create express application by including the 'express' module.
var express = require('express'); 
var app = express();

// Respond to GET requests to 'http://localhost:3000/' returning 'hello world'.
app.get('/', function(req, res){   res.send('hello world'); });
app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. So I can keep a folder with my apps anywhere on the server?

Comment: yes. just give the path to the javascript file which is the entry point of your node.js application and you are settled.